# How to upload files(images/videos/etc) to server using Stream on WCF REST API in C# properly?

Tags: c#, file-upload, stream, filestream, wcf-rest

I'm setting up a function to upload images/videos on server using WCF REST API. The files are successfully uploaded in the proper destination folder, but they end up becoming unreadable no matter what kind of file it is.

Is there something wrong within my code (especially on the FileStream-Write part) that cause that to happen? Or is it possible that the problem lies elsewhere (such as the Web.config file)?

Here's my code snippet:

```
public string uploadFile(Stream fileStream)
        {
            String fileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["fileName"];
            String destFileName = HHCWCFApp.Properties.Settings.Default.TemporaryFilePath + fileName;
            String destLink = HHCWCFApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Hyperlink + fileName;

            try
            {
                int length = 256;
                int bytesRead = 0;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    while (bytesRead == length);
                }

                fileStream.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            if (File.Exists(destFileName))
            {
                return destLink;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Not Found";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to convert to a 64 bit string.  Http does not allow binary data(images) so you must convert to a 64 bit string which converts the illegal binary http characters to valid ascii characters.

Comment: @jdweng May I ask for example of converting the file to 64 bit string? Should I put that part of the code inside that function as well?

And will that also work well for uploading videos? There's a chance that the video files will have size up to 40 MB.

Comment: There are 4 methods :   1) Convert.ToBase64String(string) 2) Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]) 3) Convert.FromBase64String(string) 4) Convert.FromBase64String(byte[])

Answer (score 0):

What kinds of files are you uploading? larger files may fall foul of the maximum request length, this is set in the web config as below

```
 <configuration> 
<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxx" /> 
</system.web>
```

Try a text file with only a few kb and if that works but the larger files don't then this could very well solve the issue. I've tested your code and there isn't a problem there.

also bear in mind that the IIS server you use may also have the maximum request length set which may override your value.

The default length is 4mb and you could write a function to retrieve the value so your client/calling code could do a check to see if the file it's going to pass exceeds the max size.

have a read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?view=netframework-4.7.2) on Microsoft's page for a bit more info.

Edit: misread the code first time round, apologies

Comment: From what I understand,  the FileStream would write or upload 256 bytes of the total file size every time it loops inside do-while until it reached the total size of the file...

Am I misunderstanding something here?